# Using map in Spark Python to manipulate Resilient Distributed Datasets

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark

I created an array using numpy's arange, and want to convert that array into a RDD using the `spark.sparkContext.parallelize`.

```
np_array = [np.arange(0,300)]
rdd_numbers = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(np_array)
times_twelve = rdd_numbers.map(lambda rdd_numbers: rdd_numbers * 12)
```

I would now like to make an RDD called times_twelve, that is basically every number in rdd_numbers multiplied by twelve. For some reason times_twelve does not print properly, any ideas where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: `For some reason times_twelve does not print properly, any ideas where I could have gone wrong`
Could you explain what is the actual output and what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: This is the actual output: `TypeError: not supported type: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ab441b1b287d> in <module>()
     33     return result_rdd.toDF(column_names)
     34 
---> 35 export_result(times_twelve)`


I get this output when calling print(times_twelve). My expected output is for times_twelve to be printed.

Comment: I am not sure as to what you are doing. `print(anyrdd)` will not print the content of the RDD. Also, I assume that the `data` that you referred to in the second line is in fact `np_array`

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments, I can say that [Shagun Sodhani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353861/shagun-sodhani) is right when he says:

> print(anyrdd) will not print the content of the RDD

If you want to see the content of the RDD on the screen, you can use the following command (recommended only for small RDDs):

```
print times_twelve.take(times_twelve.count())
```

You can check [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions) the docs about these actions supported by Spark.